# How do I install and use apache daffodil?

Tags: installation

I know this might be a dumb question, but I cannot figure out how to install and use Apache Daffodil. Any help would be appreciated. I cannot find anything helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download apache Daffodil from below url

```
https://downloads.apache.org/daffodil/3.0.0/src/apache-daffodil-3.0.0-incubating-src.zip
```

The binary Daffodil releases contain a /bin directory that contains two scripts: daffodil.bat for Windows and daffodil for Linux. These files must be executed on the command line.

- Extract downloaded zip
- Path of bin directory export as environment variables.

After that you can verify its installed or not via below cammand it will show the version of daffodil
`daffodil --version`

Global Options
-d, --debug [FILE]
Enable the interactive debugger. See the Interactive Debugger documentation for more information.

The optional FILE argument contains a list of debugger commands that are provided to the debugger as they were typed by the user.

This option cannot be used with the --trace option.

-t, --trace
Enable a trace mode. This mode prints out helpful information during every stage of parsing.

This option cannot be used with the --debug option.

-v, --verbose
Enable verbose mode and increment verbosity level. Each additional v provides a new level of information.

--version
Display the version of Daffodil.

--help
Display help message.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I do not see a /bin  directory when downloading that link and I don't see the .bat files. I'm not sure why

Comment: Please download package again from below link https://downloads.apache.org/daffodil/3.0.0/bin/apache-daffodil-3.0.0-incubating-bin.zip I think it was windows package because it's showing only bat file

Comment: If it is useful for you so please vote me up